# Why is the identity the only symmetric $0$-$1$ matrix with all eigenvalues positive?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

While thinking about [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262385/cute-eigenvalue-problem) I managed to convince myself that the identity is the only symmetric $0$-$1$ matrix with all eigenvalues positive.  However, the argument is rather low-level.  It does not give much insight into why, out of all symmetric matrices, $0$-$1$ matrices, and matrices with all eigenvalues positive, the identity is the only matrix that simultaneously has all three properties.

So my question is

> Can someone give an intuitive explanation for why the identity is the only symmetric $0$-$1$ matrix with all eigenvalues positive?

Such an explanation might entail a bigger-picture argument than the one I came up with.

For reference, here's my argument.  Let $A$ be a symmetric $0$-$1$ matrix with all eigenvalues positive.

1. Symmetric and all eigenvalues positive implies $A$ is positive definite.
2. $A$ must have all $1$'s on its diagonal.  This is because $a_{jj} = 0 \implies {\bf e}_j^T A {\bf e}_j = 0$, which contradicts positive definite.
3. $A$ must have all $0$'s for its off-diagonal elements.  This is because $A$ is symmetric implies $a_{ij} = a_{ji}$, and $a_{ij} = a_{ji} = 1 \implies ({\bf e}_i - {\bf e}_j)^T A ({\bf e}_i - {\bf e}_j) = 0$, which contradicts positive definite.
4. Thus $A$ is the identity.

---

**For clarification**: I am looking for an answer along these lines: "A symmetric matrix implies or is equivalent to $X$ about the underlying linear transformation.  A $0$-$1$ matrix implies or is equivalent to $Y$ about the underlying linear transformation.  All eigenvalues positive implies or is equivalent to $Z$ about the underlying linear transformation.  ($X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are all big-picture properties.)  [Insert argument here.]  Thus the only matrix that simultaneously satisfies $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ is the identity."

Robert Israel's answer, while nice, is not the kind of thing I'm hoping for.  I view it as a more elegant version of my own low-level argument about what form the entries of the matrix have to take, not what kind of linear transformation has these three properties.

Comment: The more interesting objects have all 2's on the main diagonal, then $0,1,-1$ elsewhere. These include the root lattices for lie algebras. http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/  and  http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/index.html#root

Comment: While attempting to answer that question, I remember convincing myself this using some kind of perron-frobenius argument, but now I can't recall it and I even suspect if it was true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two "bigger-picture" arguments that I found that I consider sufficient.

Let $A$ be a symmetric, $0$-$1$ matrix with all eigenvalues positive.

---

**Proof 1: Correlation matrices.**

Let $B$ be the diagonal matrix consisting of $1$'s where $A$ has $0$'s and $0$'s where $A$ has $1$'s.  Then $A+B$ is a correlation matrix.  Since adding nonnegative values to $A$'s diagonal can't decrease any of $A$'s eigenvalues (see, for example, [Weyl's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality)), $A+B$ has all eigenvalues positive and is thus invertible.  But the only invertible $0$-$1$ correlation matrix is the identity. (*)  Since $A+B$ is the identity, $A$ must be a diagonal matrix.  But the only invertible $0$-$1$ diagonal matrix is the identity.  Therefore, $A$ is the identity matrix.

---

**Proof 2: Linear transformations.**

Since $A$ is a real symmetric matrix it is orthogonally diagonalizable, which means that it represents a linear transformation with scaling in mutually perpendicular directions.  Since the eigenvalues are the scaling factors for the different directions, the scaling factors are all positive.  This implies that for ${\bf x} \neq {\bf 0}$, $A$ cannot map ${\bf x}$ to a vector that is perpendicular to ${\bf x}$.  (This follows geometrically, but you can also see this by remembering that positive definite implies something even stronger: $A {\bf x}$ must make an acute angle with ${\bf x}$.)

This non-orthogonality restriction between $A {\bf x}$ and ${\bf x}$ rules out any diagonal elements of $A$ being $0$, as otherwise $a_{ii} = 0$ would imply ${\bf e}_i$ and $A {\bf e}_i$ are orthogonal.

Since $A$ has all $1$'s along its diagonal, the non-orthogonality restriction now rules out any off-diagonal elements being $1$.  Suppose otherwise; i.e., that $a_{ij} = a_{ji} = 1$ with $a_{ii} = a_{jj} = 1$.  Then $A$ maps both ${\bf e}_i$ and ${\bf e}_j$ to the vector $(1,1)$ when the range of $A$ is restricted to the 2D subspace given by span$\{ {\bf e}_i, {\bf e}_j\}$.  But this means that $A$ maps ${\bf e}_i - {\bf e}_j$ to the vector $(0,0)$ when the range of $A$ is restricted to span$\{ {\bf e}_i, {\bf e}_j\}$.  Since ${\bf e}_i - {\bf e}_j$ is itself in span$\{ {\bf e}_i, {\bf e}_j\}$, this implies that ${\bf e}_i - {\bf e}_j$ and $A ({\bf e}_i - {\bf e}_j)$ are orthogonal, and we have our contradiction with the non-orthogonality restriction.

The only option left is that $A$ is the identity matrix.

(This second proof is mostly just a translation of my original proof into linear transformation terms.)

---

(*) *Added*: Marvis asked on my blog for an explanation of why the only invertible $0$-$1$ correlation matrix is the identity.  Here is such a one.  First, every correlation matrix has $1$'s on its diagonal.  Second, a $0$-$1$ correlation matrix means that any of the underlying random variables are either uncorrelated or perfectly correlated. Distinct but perfectly correlated random variables (which means you have a $1$ off-diagonal) are scalar multiples of each other. This linear dependence carries over to the correlation matrix, which therefore can’t be invertible.

Answer (score 18):

Another way of putting it: if $A$ is positive definite, then so is the $2 \times 2$ submatrix consisting of rows and columns $i$ and $j$ (for any $i \ne j$).  The determinant of this submatrix is $a_{ii} a_{jj} - a_{ij}^2$, and if the entries are in $\{0,1\}$ the only way to have $a_{ii} a_{jj} - a_{ij}^2 > 0$ is $a_{ii} = a_{jj} = 1$ and $a_{ij} = 0$.

Comment: That's a nice argument!  I was hoping for something even more intuitive than this, though.