# Eigenvalues of a binary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A = (a_{ij})$ be an $n \times n$ matrix with all entries equal to 0 or 1. Suppose that $a_{ii} = 1$ for $i = 1, \cdots, n$ and that $\det A = 1$. Then all the eigenvalues of $A$ are equal to 1.

Is this true? This question is related to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262385/eigenvalue-problem-prove-that-all-of-the-eigenvalues-of-a-are-1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not true. Consider the matrix
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
It's easy to see that $\det A = 1$.

Let's calculate charasteristic polynomial:
$$
f(\lambda) = \det (\lambda E - A) = \det \begin{pmatrix} \lambda - 1 & -1 & -1 \\ 0 & \lambda-1 & -1 \\ -1 & 0 & \lambda - 1 \end{pmatrix}
=\lambda^3-3\lambda^2+2\lambda-1
$$

Eigenvalues are the roots of $f(\lambda)$, so cannot be equal to $1$.